# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: stock_name

Tags: sqlite, flask, node-sqlite3

```
#user_input.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)


def process_user_input(data):
    
    # Retrieve user input from the data
    stock_name = data.get('stockName')

    # Create a new connection and cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/SQLite/pythonstock/database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT price FROM stocks WHERE lower(stockName) = ?", (stock_name.lower(),))

    # Fetch the result
    row = c.fetchone()
    if row:
        price = row[0]  # Access the first column (price)
        # Perform further operations with the retrieved price
    else:
        # Handle the case when no row is found for the given stock_name
        price = None  # or any appropriate default value or error handling

    # Close the cursor and connection
    c.close()
    conn.close()

    processed_input = price

    # Create a JSON-serializable response
    response = {'processed_input': processed_input}
    return response
def process_user_input1(data):
    print("Process_user_input1 started")
    # Retrieve user input from the data
    stock_name = data.get('stockName')
    BRstage=data.get('BRstage')
   
   
    # Create a new connection and cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/SQLite/pythonstock/database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('update stocks set BRstage=BRstage where stockName=stock_name')
   
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    processed_input1='success'
    response = {'processed_input1': processed_input1}
    return response


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Steven\stock.investing.decision.making\my-app\flask-app\main.py", line 25, in process_user_input_route1   
    result = process_user_input1(data)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Steven\stock.investing.decision.making\my-app\flask-app\user_input.py", line 57, in process_user_input1   
    c.execute('UPDATE stocks SET BRstage = ? WHERE lower(stockName) = ?', (BRstage, stock_name.lower()))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: stock_name
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2023 22:11:41] "POST /process_user_input1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: I don't see the sql from the traceback in the code;  this  query `c .execute('update stocks set BRstage=BRstage where stockName=stock_name')` will give that error.

Comment: So where do you think that the problem lies?

Answer (score 1):

Fix the problem in this line `c.execute('update stocks set BRstage=BRstage where stockName=stock_name')`. It needs to use parameter substitution (bound variable) for `stock_name` because as written it is looking for a column named `stock_name`. Or maybe it's an incomplete picture of what is going on. The traceback complains about line 57. There are at most (including blank lines) 56 lines of posted code.